# Can I filter sidebar directories by name (in sublime text 3) to quickly find node module, for example?

Tags: sublimetext3

[image: Example]

Here is my example, where I could have some input to filter directory subfolders.

Answer (score 1):

The direct answer to the question is that this is not possible; the list of files and folders in the side bar is controlled by what folders you add and the settings that you include/exclude files and folders from within those folders. In theory you could try to modify the settings to change what appears in the side bar, but every time those settings change the file catalog needs to be rebuilt, which is something that can take some time (particularly in something with a large `node_modules` folder). It also causes all of the folders in the side bar to fold up.

The expected workflow is more designed around working with files than with working with groups of folders and that workflow centers around the `Goto Anything` panel.  Choosing `Goto > Goto Anything` in the menu will open a panel showing you a list of every file that is currently contained in the side bar (except binary files).

The panel can filter text via fuzzy matching using as many search terms as you want (in any order you want) and will move the most likely matches closer to the top of the list. It also learns over time what files you pick when you use certain filters.

For your use case here you can open the panel and use a filter like `node_modules` or `nmod/` to filter to files in the `node_modules/` directory, `acorn/` to see only files that exist in folders that match `acorn`, or a combination. You can also include fragments of filenames like `lodash/ indjs` to bring the `index.js` of the `lodash/ package to the top of the list.

The best way to get a feel for how this works is to play with it a little bit. Note also that the context menu in open files has a `Reveal in side bar` command that will focus the side bar on that file, which can be a handy way to see the other siblings of files you have open.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. It was really helpful.